What exactly is recursion depth in Python?
From my understanding, when a recursive function is executed in Python, a stack is created internally, containing the function's calls. I assumed that the recursion depth is the number of functions in this stack, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
Consider the following pseudo-factorial function :
def f(n):
    if (n == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return n*f(n-1)

When we call f with the argument n = 1, it should directly return 1 after going through the if conditional.
If I set the max recursion depth to 3 using
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(3)

And then I call , a RecursionError is raised.
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Why does this happen? Shouldn't the stack contain just one call to f, which should then be popped, right as f(1) returns 1?
So, what exactly does recursion depth mean in Python?

The stack is used for all function calls, not just recursive ones. Although we call it the recursion limit, it's actually the limit on depth of all of them. It's generally hard to exceed it without recursion, hence the name.

If you're doing this in the REPL, there are internal calls there, which use the stack.

I also get "RecursionError: cannot set the recursion limit to 3 at the recursion depth 12: the limit is too low" with 3.10 and 3.11. In 3.12 I get the same but at depth 9.

@Barmar Even so, I'm unable to see how a stack of 3 (or more) function calls is created in this example. Can you please elaborate?

It's hard to know exactly what's going on internally. Suffice it to say that it's using 2 levels of recursion, and then it hits the limit when it calls your function.

It's an implementation detail you shouldn't really mess with--there can be a few calls used by the interpreter to set up your program. This feature is a footgun/design flaw in Python that makes people think they can buy more stack space to fit their inefficient algorithms into, but the truth is it just risks crashing the interpreter. Don't use recursion for anything linear in Python, only logarithmic depth, at which point you won't need to change the stack limit.
